# How to get Transparent Accessory View in UITableViewCell? (w/ Screenshot)

Tags: iphone, uikit, uitableview, interface-builder

I use a custom UITableViewCell from a nib. The accessory view is a Detail Disclosure Indicator . The problem is that the background color of the UITableViewCell behind the accessory view is not getting rendered (see image / source below). Any clues? Also, here are some things that I tried but did NOT work:

**Things that DID NOT work:**
- Setting the backgroundColor of the accessory view to clearColor
- Setting the contentView.opaque of the cell to FALSE
- Setting the contentView.opaque of the Table View to FALSE
- Setting a non-default accessory view for the cell

[alt text http://www.chicknchoke.com/so/IMG_8028.png](http://www.chicknchoke.com/so/IMG_8028.png)

```
    -(void)showTablePrep
    {
        myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 416) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        myTableView.dataSource = self;
        myTableView.delegate = self;
        myTableView.delaysContentTouches = FALSE;
        myTableView.opaque = FALSE;
        myTableView.rowHeight = 60;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"SlideUp" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];

        [myTableView setCenter:CGPointMake(myTableView.center.x, myTableView.center.y-436)];
        [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:myTableView];

        [UIView commitAnimations];


    }




- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    FriendsCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCellID"];

    if (cell == nil){

        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FriendsCellView" owner:self options:nil];

        cell = (FriendsCell*)[nib objectAtIndex:0];

        if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0){

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];


        }else{

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];


        }
        cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.contentView.opaque = FALSE;
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


    if(f

riendsCounter > indexPath.row){


            cell.titleLabel.text = @"Label";
            cell.descLabel.text = @"Description goes here";

        }else{

            cell.titleLabel.text = @"";
            cell.descLabel.text = @"";
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

        }

        }

        return cell;    
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're drawing the background color for your cell incorrectly. A `UITableViewCell` will be arranged so that the `contentView` and `accessoryView` sit side-by-side. (This is done so that the `contentView` can clip its content so it doesn't overlap with the accessory view) The problem is not that the accessory view is opaque, it's that the gray background is simply not drawn behind the accessory view.

The correct way of customizing the background drawn behind a `UITableViewCell` is to customize its `backgroundView`. I haven't tried this, but since you're only changing the color, you might be able to simply set the `backgroundColor` color on the `backgroundView` to your desired color.

Comment: I also wanted to mention that there's a really great overview of customizing `UITableView` drawing here: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html

Comment: This worked for me:

cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init ];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

Comment: @joshaidan Do not forget to release the view you created (unless you use ARC): cell.backgroundView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: @manicaesar yeah I'm using autorelease, I think I caught that when I ran analyze. Thanks!

Comment: Also to remember: "If you want to change the background color of a cell, do so in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method of your table view delegate"

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by having a look at the subviews of my custom table view cell.

It seems like the accessory view has a button sitting over it.  By finding this button in the subviews and changing its color, i was able to update the background color behind the accessory button.

```
<UIButton: 0x3b4d690; frame = (277 0; 43 75); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x3b3e0b0>>

for (UIView *aSubView in self.subviews) {
    if ([aSubView isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        aSubView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I was only able to reach this button within the

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
```

method of my custom table view cell class.  I've used this successfully within my app to display a different highlight color when the user selects a cell.  This should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this problem on iOS7 but adding

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

in

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

and you modify your background and other bakcgrounds here :

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Add your Colour.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexColor:HIGHLIGHT_COLOR]];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Reset Colour.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexColor:UNHIGHLIGHT_COLOR]];   
}
```