# TableView Cell Color

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, custom-view

```
我现在遇到了个问题，如何使uitableview cell 的背景色填满整个cell ，以下是我的代码。但它不能正常工作、、、
```

Picture shows:

[image: http://www.flickr.com/photos/53054715@N05/4898445104/]

How can I code that set the color fill in cell view?

My code is below, but it does not work well.

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor =[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor =[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Transparent Accessory View in UITableViewCell? (w/ Screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503664/how-to-get-transparent-accessory-view-in-uitableviewcell-w-screenshot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it works!

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
  {
  [tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
  return 1;
  }