# Setting custom color for background of UITableViewCell accessory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to get my table view cells to show a custom checkmark image when selected. The issue is that the color behind the checkmark image is gray instead of the custom cell color that I provide.

I'm aware this question has been asked before - I've read through and attempted to the following suggestions:

- [Wrong Background Color in Accessory View on iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406149/wrong-background-color-in-accessory-view-on-ios7)
- [How to get Transparent Accessory View in UITableViewCell? (w/ Screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503664/how-to-get-transparent-accessory-view-in-uitableviewcell-w-screenshot)
- [Altering the background color of cell.accessoryView and cell.editingAccessoryView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484511/altering-the-background-color-of-cell-accessoryview-and-cell-editingaccessoryvie)

Among others. The general consensus seems to that changing the color of the cell's `backgroundView` will affect the accessory, but this does not seem to be the case for me. Here is my current code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_checkImage];

    [self setCellColor:_customColor forCell:cell];
}

- (void)setCellColor:(UIColor *)color forCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.backgroundColor = color;
 }
```

Note that my `checkImage` has a transparent background. Upon selecting a cell, the background of my cell changes to my `customColor`, but the background on the accessory remains gray. SOS!

Answer (score 1):

> The general consensus seems to that changing the color of the cell's backgroundView will affect the accessory

That is correct. The problem is that you are not doing that. You are saying this:

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = color;
```

But `cell.backgroundView` is nil, so that line is pointless. You need to *give* your cell a background view before you can set the color of that view.

Comment: I changed to this, and I'm still having the same issue: 
`- (void)setCellColor:(UIColor *)color forCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
    cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = color;
    
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = color;
    cell.backgroundColor = color;
}`

Comment: check this. UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.backgroundColor = color;
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:view];

Answer (score 0):

Use

```swift
self.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red
```

to change the `UITableViewCell` background color when selected and

```swift
self.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
```

to change the `UITableViewCell` background color when unselected/default